# Move views with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-animation

I am working on an application where I'm using `AppBarLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `NestedScrollView`. I have successfully implemented this and it is working fine.

Now what I am trying to do is to move the white circle more faster than its background while decreasing it's size so that it fits inside `Toolbar` on collapse. Meanwhile, these search and settings button fade in/out with scroll, and when it's completely collapsed, I want to show them as `MenuItems`.

Here's the image
[image: Here's the Image]

What I've done so far:

1. I am able to show/hide `MenuItem` when it's collapsed/expanded.
2. I am able to provide parallax effect to the view.
3. Explore many libraries, but couldn't find any clue of what I want to do.

What I need:

1. Any indication/direction how to do it or where to look for it.

Below is my `xml` file for reference if anyone needs.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.HomePage">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/main_menu_topbg"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@color/background"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/background"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-75dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imgBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_circle"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcyHomePage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@color/background"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white"
            android:contentDescription="@string/search"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:contentDescription="@string/settings" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```